# Translating Operations on Solutions to that of Equations

Tags: galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, irreducible-polynomials, symmetric-functions, resultant

Let $a, b$ be two algebraic numbers, $f(x), g(x)$ their minimal polynomials over $\mathbb{Q}$ respectively. Suppose the set of roots of $f$ is $$A = \{a=a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n\}$$ and the set of roots of $g$ is $$B = \{b=b_1, b_2, \cdots, b_m\}.$$

According to this [wikipedia page - other applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant), there is a way to build a polynomial, one of whose roots being $a+b$, from the coefficients of $f$ and $g$. Explicitly, the polynomial in $x$ is $res_y(f(y),g(x-y))$.

However, it is by no means the *minimal polynomial* of $a+b$. This is not surprising, since the coefficients of $f$ and $g$ only encode the *unordered* sets A and B, in which $a$ and $b$ are not specified in any way.

Hence, instead of looking at the element $a+b$, I look at the set $S = \{a_i+b_j|a_i\in A, b_j\in B\}$ and come up with two questions.

#### Questions

1. How do the Galois groups of $a$ and $b$ relate to the Galois groups of the elements in $S$?
2. Which elements in $S$ have the same minimal polynomials?
3. Is the polynomial (in $x$) $res_y(f(y),g(x-y))$ the product $P$ of the minimal polynomials in the last question? If not, is there a general description to get $P$ from the coefficients of $f$ and $g$?

#### Examples

Let $$a=\sqrt{2}, b=\sqrt{3}.$$ Then $$f=x^2-2, g=x^2-3$$ and $$A=\{\sqrt{2}, -\sqrt{2}\}, B=\{\sqrt{3}, -\sqrt{3}\}.$$ The polynomial obtained by the resultant is $$res_y(f(y),g(x-y)) = x^4 - 10x^2+1,$$ which is irreducible whose set of roots is $$S = \{\pm\sqrt{2}\pm\sqrt{3}\}.$$

In this case the Galois group of $a+b$ is isomorphic to the product of the Galois groups of $a$ and $b$ (1). All four elements in $S$ share the same minimal polynomial (2). And the minimal polynomial of $a+b$ is obtainable from the coefficients of $f$ and $g$ by the resultant formula (3).

Comment: The Galois group $G=Gal(L/\Bbb{Q})$, $L$ a splitting field of $f(x)g(x)$ obviously tells a story. The size of the orbit of $a_i+b_j$ gives the degree of the minimal polynomial of $a_i+b_j$. Repetitions among $a_i+b_j$ lead to factors with multiplicity $>1$. For example, with $a=\sqrt2+\sqrt3$, $b=\sqrt2$ the resultant comes out as
$$res_y(f(y),g(x-y))=(x^2-3)^2(x^4-22x^2+25),$$ the quartic obviously the minimal polynomial of $a+b$. If I find the time to translate this into something coherent, I will give it a shot.

Comment: Hmm.. yeah I will wait until you have time. I don't understand how $f(x)g(x)$ relates to $a+b$..

Comment: Hmm. A good point. May be it doesn't. But its spitting field is a Galois extension containing all the $a_i$s and $b_j$s, and hence also their sums (giving a sufficiently large playground to find the minimal polynomials of all the $a_i+b_j$s. May be somebody else can grab the wheel.

Comment: My guess is actually that the resultant I provided in the original post is very closed to the product of all minimal polynomials (without redundancy) I want. But I cannot find a statement nor prove it.